# Password Meter Info not showing required info in Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, password

We are facing a strange behavior on the registration page of `Magento 2.3.1`

This is how it should work with the Password Meter: https://potatocommerce.com/blog/how-to-configure-password-meter-in-magento-2

But in our shop, it only shows Password Weak, Medium or Strong or very Strong, but not the field below with necessary info on how customer should apply password (Minimum lenght of this field must be greater or equal etc...)

Does anyone out there know, how I can make this field make show up as per https://potatocommerce.com/blog/how-to-configure-password-meter-in-magento-2 maybe even with this color view there...?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is your custom form. Please, add these fields and script in your phtml form. Make sure the div tags should be within form tags. and script tag should be outside of tags.

```
       <div class="field password required">
            <label for="password" class="label"><span>Password</span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="Password" class="input-text" data-password-min-length="8" data-password-min-character-sets="3" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true">
                <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite">
                    <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password Strength')) ?>:
                        <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No Password')) ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field confirmation required">
            <label for="password-confirmation" class="label"><span>Confirm Password</span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" title="Confirm Password" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}" aria-required="true">
            </div>
        </div>
```

add this script in similar form.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">{
        ".field.password": {
            "passwordStrengthIndicator": {
                "formSelector": "form.form-login"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If this solves your problem, don't forget to mark it as a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Finally we figured it out. An external extension was causing the error. Error was described as "our module affects Core validation. It's necessary to use the custom validation for fields which change our module (quantity fields). But it was not envisaged to invoke parent core validation on pages, where our module doesn't produce impact. That's why the validation worked not quite correctly." We got the validation-mixin.js changed and all works fine now.

Comment: That's great!!!